# x-axis starting value for diverging plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the "x-axis starting value" from the diverging bar chart below (extracted from [here](https://www.onceupondata.com/2019/01/25/ggplot2-divergent-bars/)), so that the vertical axis is set at 25 instead of 0. And therefore the bars are drawn from 25 and not 0.

For instance, I want this chart:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

---

**EDIT**
It it not the *label* I want to change, it is how the *data* is plotted. My apologies if I wasn't clear. See example below:

Another example to make it clear:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide computed labels to an (x-)scale via `scale_x_continuous(labels = function (x) x + 25)`.

If you also want to change the *data*, you’ll first need to offset the x-*values* by the equivalent amount (in the opposite direction):

Example:

```
df = tibble(Color = c('red', 'green', 'blue'), Divergence = c(5, 10, -5))
offset = 2

df %>%
    mutate(Divergence = Divergence - offset) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(x = Divergence, y = Color) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = function (x) x + offset)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry my original post wasn't clear. I want to update how the *data* is plotted, and not only the *labels*. See my edited post please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not 100% clear on your intended outcome but you can "shift" your data by adding/subtracting 25 from each value, e.g.

Original plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

set.seed(123)

gapminder_subset <- gapminder %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, continent, year)) %>% 
  filter(year == "1997" | year == "2007") %>% 
  select(-continent) %>% 
  filter(name == "gdpPercap") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  mutate(gdp_change = ((`2007` - `1997`) / `1997`) * 100) %>% 
  sample_n(15)


ggplot(data = gapminder_subset,
       aes(x = country, y = gdp_change)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: example_3.png]

subtract 25:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

set.seed(123)

gapminder_subset <- gapminder %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, continent, year)) %>% 
  filter(year == "1997" | year == "2007") %>% 
  select(-continent) %>% 
  filter(name == "gdpPercap") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  mutate(gdp_change = ((`2007` - `1997`) / `1997`) * 100) %>% 
  sample_n(15)


ggplot(data = gapminder_subset,
       aes(x = country, y = gdp_change)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: example_4.png]

If you combine that with my original relabelling I think that's the solution:

```
ggplot(data = gapminder_subset,
       aes(x = country, y = gdp_change - 25)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-25, 0, 25, 50),
                     labels = c(0, 25, 50, 75))
```

[image: example_5.png]

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I did not expressed myself correctly. It is not the *label* that I want to change, it is how the data is plotted. For instance, the bars from Gentoo and chinstrap should be shorter if we plot them starting from 25, and the one from Adelie should be larger. Le me know if this information is still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The answers that existed at the time that I'm writing this are suggesting to change the data or to change the label. Here, I'm proposing to change neither the data nor the labels, and instead just change where the starting position of a bar is.

First, for reproducibility, I took @jared_mamrot's approach for the data subset.

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

gapminder_subset <- gapminder %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, continent, year)) %>% 
  filter(year == "1997" | year == "2007") %>% 
  select(-continent) %>% 
  filter(name == "gdpPercap") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  mutate(gdp_change = ((`2007` - `1997`) / `1997`) * 100) %>% 
  sample_n(15)
```

Then, you can set `xmin = after_scale(25)`. You'll get a warning that `xmin` doesn't exists, but it *does* exist after the bars are reparameterised to rectangles in the ggplot2 internals (which is after the x-scale has seen the data to determine limits). This effectively changes the position where bars start.

```r
ggplot(gapminder_subset,
       aes(gdp_change, country)) +
  geom_col(aes(xmin = after_scale(25)))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic approach! Awesome!